# What causes heart rate to spike upon *decreasing* running pace?

Tags: cardio, heart-rate, sprinting

It seems opposite to what one would intuitively expect… one would think that when cardio activity demands increase then that is when the heart rate would follow but it seems inverse to that: only when you stop running so fast and decrease the speed does the really high heart rate zones occur. Why is this?